# view.setChocieMode(CHOICE_MULTIPLE_MODE)

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView view=getListView();
    this.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
 }}
```

Here he my xml file that include a listview and i am reading data from string array and i want to give a user choice to select item but choice mode is not working means this line in java code              this.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

```
 <ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:entries="@array/options"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    />
```

Comment: can you share Log-cat error please.??

Comment: You didn't set selector as background.

Comment: i am not getting any error list is showing all the data but the problem is list not showing chekboxex for selection

Comment: you have to make three things : 1) a Model class which contains id,name and boolean isChecked  after that use getter and setter method 2) You have to make the baseAdapter class then in getView method you have to implement OnclickListener on the row. 3) make a single row xml file which contain textView and checkbox ,where checkbox visibility is earlier INVISIABLE. when user touches the single row in list item you have to make checkbox visiable and when he double tab that row then you have to make it's visiability INVISIABLE again .

Comment: why i use adapter i am getting data from string resource file as you can see in listview enteries attribute and i am using adapter listener for getting selected item data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample code

```
public class MyListPage extends ListActivity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savein) {
    super.onCreate(savein);
    // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity  

    String[] options=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.options);

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listview.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
            android.R.id.text1, options)); 
     listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
}
}
```

Comment: check edited answer. Now string array fetch from resources and remove from .xml. I hope this work.

Comment: what is the purpose of third parameter in setlistadapter constructor

Comment: android.R.id.text1 what this does?

Comment: android.R.id.text1 is the id of the TextView defined in the android's predefined layout ex: android.layout.simple_list_item1.

Comment: got it bro Thanks !!